# Saving DIV contents as HTML/HTM file (non-image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to save out a div content (code and all) block by it's `ID`/`CLASS` on button click as an `html` file. Due to specifics of the project saving it out as an image through canvas wasn't an option.

So far I've tried the `download` attribute, which seems to be unsupported by Safari 10 and back, as well as, IE in general. From there I moved on to `FileSaver.js` which worked like a dream until I started incorporating required fields into it. After I did some reading on their site, it seems this is an issue for others as well.

I've prepared this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdcutter/ynwew6pc/3/) to give you an idea of what I'm working with code wise and for a point of view for any suggestions out there.

Comment: Maybe this is something that should be done on the back end?

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/

Comment: @KrzysztofKaźmierczak I think it does lay somewhere in this method. FileSaver.js pulls from a similar blob file, but in IE and Safari it produces one of two results for me. 1. Allowing for download before the div is created – basically downloading nothing but an empty html file. Or 2. Refreshing the page without downloading any content. I'm still reading up more on it to see if I'm missing any specifics in its calls or setup.

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify But it requires flash ;(

Comment: It seems like generating the file on the server side is the safest solution: http://tutorialzine.com/2011/05/generating-files-javascript-php/

Comment: Flash is definitely a no-go in this round of things. As for the generating files, this is pretty rad, but I'm not able to grab all of the DIV with it. When I say the content, I mean it's code and all. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that before (updating the above just in case). I'm toying with this though in its script.js and download.php to see if I can adjust.

Comment: So far I'm thinking your link to the BLOB option may still be the right solution. So digging in there too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130645/discussion-between-cutter-and-krzysztof-kazmierczak).